# Authenticity Of Tirmidhi Hadith: 3521?

Tags: hadith, authenticity, ilm-mustalah-al-hadith

What is the authenticity of the following narration:-

> Abu Umamah narrated:
>
> “The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) supplicated with many supplications of
> which we did not preserve a thing. We said: ‘O Messenger of Allah, you
> supplicated with many supplications of which we did not preserve a
> thing.’ He (ﷺ) said: ‘Should I not direct you to what will include all
> of that? That you say: O Allah, we ask You from the good of what Your
> Prophet Muhammad (ﷺ) asked You for, and we seek refuge in You from the
> evil of that which Your Prophet Muhammad (ﷺ) sought refuge in You
> from, and You are the one from Whom aid is sought, and it is for You
> to fulfill, and there is no might or power except by Allah." (Jami`
> at-Tirmidhi 3521)

I found this narration in book of Adhkar I have, but when I checked it on Sunnah.com, I saw that it was marked as "Daif".

Comment: https://islamqa.info/en/answers/179426/can-he-say-a-duaa-based-on-a-daeef-hadith-whilst-prostrating

Comment: @UmH - The website you cited says that Layth ibn Abi Sulaym is not to be relied upon. But how is this possible? He is a narrator in [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:2066d)

Comment: @UmH - Sister, can you please explain?

Comment: @UmH - I traced it with [THIS](https://isnad.io/rawi/10957?query=%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%84%D9%8A%D8%AB%20%D8%A8%D9%86%20%D8%A3%D8%A8%D9%8A%20%D8%B3%D9%84%D9%8A%D9%85) link. Please sister can you explain why Imam Muslim narrated from Layth Ibn Abi Sulaym if he is weak?

Comment: Imam Muslim has only used him as corroboration. He says that [this](https://sunnah.com/muslim:2066a) hadith has also been narrated by ليث ​and  أبو إسحاق الشيباني simultaneously with several other narrators. It does not mean that a hadith narrated by ليث ​ alone fulfills the conditions of Muslim

Comment: And I am a brother, not a sister.

Answer (score 0):

In another website (which is still Sunan Tirmidhi, still the same book) it usually also appear the grade of the hadith from Abu Isa. For this hadith, it said:

قَالَ أَبُو عِيسَى هَذَا حَدِيثٌ حَسَنٌ غَرِيبٌ

Translation: "Abu Isa said: This hadith is hasan gharib" (usually at sunnah.com it's dha'if).

Hasan Gharib means the isnad is good but conveyed by only one narrator.
Hasan Gharib is different from just Hasan (or hasan li ghairihi), Hasan Li ghairihi is where a hadith is dha'if but become hasan because of other hadith from different narrator.

Personally I wouldn't practice it

Wallahu a'lam